# What type of socket is needed if the documentation states "17 Way Molex SIL 6471"

Tags: plug

I have a coin validator (for a fruit/slot machine). The main connector on the board has 4 pins then a space and then 12 pins (see picture).

The manual states the following "Connector types used:- 15 Way Molex SIL 6471 or 17 Way Molex SIL 6471"

I've Googled "17 way Molex SIL 6471" and not managed to find any.

I wondered if I could use a 4-way and a 12-way side by side so I looked for those and found references on eBay to a "MX-6471-***121*** Plug wire-board KK 254" which looked promising but then I also saw a "MX-6471-***131*** Plug wire-board KK 254" and a "MX-6471-***141*** Plug wire-board KK 254"?

At that point I stopped and came here to ask. Can anyone help point me in the right direction of what socket I need for this?

The plug is approximately 48mm long, 5mm wide.

[image: Picture of plug]

Comment: Measure the pin pitch (e.g. 1" / 2.54mm) then just search on DigiKey (or similar) for 17-pin connectors. Any decent manufacturer's datasheet will show a drawing with all the dimensions you need to match to your connector.

Comment: You could go to the product page and see mating connector series: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0022012025_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

Comment: Google molex 6471, select a major supplier, then filter for the 17-circuit version.  I think all 6571 shells are Single In Line, so don't worry about that. You will also need to buy the crimp connectors (pin sockets).

Comment: And to go the whole way, get a little blanking plug for the missing pin. This prevents accidental misalignment. It's easier to measure the distance from first pin to last and divide by 16 to get the pitch but given the 48mm it looks like 2.54mm.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers folks. I've managed to find one on RS. Cheers :-)